# How to get rid of syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was getting

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

in Command Prompt when trying to install and test ruby.

```
require 'mysql2'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(host: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: 'password1')

sql = 'select now() as timestamp'

result = client.query(sql)
    puts row['time stamp']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing `do`.

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(host: 'localhost', username: 'root', password: 'password1')

sql = 'select now() as timestamp'

result = client.query(sql) do # <----
    puts row['timestamp']
end
```

FYI, `time stamp` should be `timestamp`. (This is not direct cause of the syntax error).